# Count # of Nodes in Binary Search Tree Smaller than Key

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Been working on this for hours, and I still can't seem to come up with a working solution.

[image: The Problem]

11.13 Binary Tree Guided Information Flow
X279: Binary Search Tree Small Count Exercise

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it depends on specification of the `Binary Search Tree`, which you didn't provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You are counting both the sub tree to the left and right of the current node when in the `else if` case, thus counting the whole tree. Try spliting the two recursive function calls up in different cases.</s>

My first answer didn't work. This new one does.

The first problem is you are actually not counting anything, you are just recursively going over every node and checking its value.

Secondly, the check also does not work as intended. You have to check if the current node should be counted or not. You should also go further down the tree to count there as those nodes may be smaller than the key.

My working implementation:

```
public int BSTsmallcount(BinNode root, int key)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (root.value() < key) {
        count++;
        count += BSTsmallcount(root.left(), key);
        count += BSTsmallcount(root.right(), key);
    }
    else {
        count += BSTsmallcount(root.left(), key);
    }

    return count;
}
```